# Base URL of Nuxt App is added to Axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

My API baseURL: `API_URL="http://localhost:8080/api/"`

My Axios config:

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
}
```

My request:

```
this.$axios.$get(`categories/like/${name}`)
```

The result:

```
xhr.js?b50d:177 GET http://localhost:3000/http/localhost:8080/api/categories/like/G 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems like nuxt is adding the baseURL of the nuxt app to my axios baseURL

Comment: Do you have a Github repo?

Comment: @kissu it's a private repo unfortunately, what info do you want?

Comment: @BorisWinter are you sure that your url in the config is 
API_URL="http://localhost:8080/api/"
and not API_URL="http/localhost:8080/api/"

Comment: No, its `API_URL="http/localhost:8080/api/"`, why?

Comment: Alright, let me guess, you do have a typo here, right? You do have `API_URL="http/localhost:8080/api/"` rather than `API_URL="http://localhost:8080/api/"`? Hence the error..

Comment: Btw, you should probably set just `API_URL="http://localhost:8080/api"` (without the ending `/`) as suggested by Brahim. Usually, you do append the `/` prefix with axios. At least, I've always saw it written this way, to avoid future errors like `/api//my-path`.